# Congruences - Change of Modulo Base

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Let's say I have the following congruence:

**x ≡  y (mod b)**

Is there a formular, theorem, or algorithm that gives the new (congruent) relationship between **x** and **y** when I change the modulus base **b** to something else.
Change to something else could be any arithmetic operation or combination of operations performed on **b**.

Comment: $\forall$k$\in$$\mathbb{N}$, kx$\equiv$ky$\space$ (mod kb)

Comment: There are formal algorithms for converting from one CRR base to an extended one, and computing a remainder in CRR.  They are very complicated though.

Comment: @DanielV I'll like to know more about those

Comment: Nice answers, but I was hoping for something more complex,like converting from a general unknown base **mod b** to a specific number e.g **mod 3**

Comment: $$\begin{array} {cc} 1 \equiv 1  \pmod 3 & 1 \equiv 1 \pmod 5 \\ 4 \equiv 1 \pmod 3 & 4 = 4 \pmod 5 \\ 7 \equiv 1 \pmod 3 & 7 \equiv 2 \pmod 5 \end{array}$$ so what do think the result of converting $1 \pmod 3$ to $\pmod 5$ should be ?

Comment: The real problem is that your map it's not well defined. Take for example $n=1,m=4$ then $n\equiv m\equiv 1\mod 3$ but $n\equiv 1\mod 5$ and $m\equiv 4\mod 5$. Then the problem is, when want to convert $1\mod 3$ should i send it in $1\mod 5$ or $4\mod 5$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only if what you change to is a divisor of $b$. In that case it's straight-forward. For instance, if we have
$$
x\equiv 7\pmod{15}
$$
we can easily see that
$$
x\equiv 2\pmod 5
$$
However, other than bases $5$ and $3$ (and possibly $1$ if you count that), there is no other modular base where we know exactly what $x$ is.

For multiples of $15$, we can rule out a lot of options, for instance we know that
$$
x\equiv 7\text{ or }22\pmod{30}
$$
and for numbers that share factors with $15$, we can similarily rule out a few options. For instance, we must have
$$
x\equiv 2\text{ or }7\pmod{10}
$$
because of the shared factor $5$ between $10$ and $15$. Basically, if we reduce to modulo $5$, the two must give the same class for $x$, and the two classes modulo $10$ that give $2$ modulo $5$ are $2$ and $7$.

If you know $x$ in other modular bases, those could be combined using the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), as long as they're not contradictory ($x\equiv 3\pmod{10}$ would, for instance, be contradictory to the above example). For instance if we also know that $x\equiv 0\pmod 2$, then we necessarily have
$$
x\equiv 22\pmod{30}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $x\equiv y \mod b$ is equivalent to say that $\exists k\in \mathbb Z$ such that $x-y=kb$.

Then if you take any $q|b$ then $x-y=kq\bar b$ so $$x\equiv y\mod q$$